# How show a message over a fullscreen?

Tags: c#, c, fullscreen, send

Well.. I want to do a thing, but I don't know how searching informations to do that.

How can I send a message over the game's screen?
For example: Just writing "Hello World" on a game running in fullscreen.

I know C and C#, I'd like some tips how to do that. What a need to study etc.

Thanks,
I wait a response :)

Comment: What game are you talking about?

Comment: Are you in control of the full screen or are you trying to write on top of a screen of another running full screen app?

Comment: I am talking a "generic game", the most using DirectX or OpenGL. And until now I just know to program in "windows environment". In a game running in fullscreen, how can i send a message: "hello world" over the game, in the middle of screen. I don't know anything about DirectX or OpenGL programming. What exactly I need study?

Comment: Have you considered using XNA?

Comment: No, I never used XNA. For example, in Counter-Strike running in fullscreen, I can send a message "hello world" the middle of screen, inside him, using XNA?
I thought XNA was just to make games, not to do what i intended.
Then i can do that with XNA? If yes, then the question is answered.

Comment: I think he wants to do what he says - make text appear on the screen while a fullscreen application is running through DirectX or OpenGL. This is not my domain but from what I know you can either try to hook into the game and make it blit your text into it's buffer right before updating video memory, or try to see if two applications can mess with video memory at the same time (and be able to make your application always come out on top right before a refresh). So like I said, I have no idea how, but maybe other people will be less confused after reading this.

Comment: If you are using C#, why not creating an image with the message which you want to show, and using windows forms you can play with the region of the form (so you could have only the text) then set that form to top most? I haven't tried it to be honest, but it could be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want is to hook the DirectX context of the game and put your graphics inside.
It's the same way as Steam does for its overlay.
You can find the example here:
[Screen capture and Overlays for Direct3D 9, 10 and 11](http://spazzarama.com/2011/03/14/c-screen-capture-and-overlays-for-direct3d-9-10-and-11-using-api-hooks/)